# Html CSS - Apply style to all elements inside a class?

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc

I have a weird situation, I have a table, in every row I have an ajax form.
`Form` is not allowed in `tr`, but it's allowed in `td`. So I had to place all column inside a `td` and manually match the sizing. The problem is the padding and margin that HtmlHelpers(ASP.Net MVC Razor) add, cause the content not to be aligned under the correct header column.

I need to write a css that gets rid of all margin and padding of all items recursively, inside a given class. How can I do that?

Or is there an easier way to force align the content under the header?

```
<table style="width: 100%">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th style="width: 5%">Id</th>
        <th style="width: 35%">Material</th>
        <th style="width: 60%">Description</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    @foreach (var item in Model.items){
        <tr>
            <td class="noMarginAndPadding" colspan="3">
            @using (@Ajax.BeginForm()){
                <span style="width: 5%">@Html.TextBoxFor(i => item.Id)</span>
                <span style="width: 35%">@Html.TextBoxFor(i => item.Name)</span>
                <span style="width: 60%">@Html.TextBoxFor(i => item.Description)</span>
            }
             </td>
        </tr>
    }
</tbody>
```

Comment: In theory, `td.noMarginAndPadding * { margin: 0; padding: 0; }` should do it. It would be a bit easier if you could http://jsfiddle.net your client-side form with the relevant stylesheet as well.

Comment: I'm afraid that won't work. I tried the same thing. I had a php script dynamically assign a class to the html tag, according to the browser sort (class="firefox", etc.). That worked. Additionally, I put this in my CSS: `.opera * {letter-spacing: .002em}`, but that did not work.

Comment: does adding the child combinator selector (>) make any difference? ie td.noMarginAndPadding>* { margin: 0; padding: 0; }

Comment: these solutions did not work, not sure what's causing all the extra spacing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<span>`s are inline elements they cannot accept width,height..

To allow the  to accept width, add display: block; to the Span's CSS.

Otherwise use Div instead of Span

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Result", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId ="result"}))
 {
      <div style="width:5%;float:left;text-align:center" >@Html.TextBoxFor(i => item.Id)</div>
      <div style="width: 35%;float:left;text-align:center">@Html.TextBoxFor(i => item.Name)</div>
      <div style="width: 60%;float:left;text-align:center">@Html.TextBoxFor(i => item.Description)</div>
 }
```